# Importing a dependency's dependency emits eslint(node/no-extraneous-import) error

Tags: node.js, eslint

When I import my dependency's dependency eslint will emit [node/no-extraneous-import](https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/blob/v11.1.0/docs/rules/no-extraneous-import.md) error since that package is not in my package.json. What is the proper way to handle the situation?

As an example, using Chakra-UI only requires `@chakra-ui/react` package which has required packages as dependencies. If I want to import the default theme I can do it as `import defaultTheme from '@chakra-ui/theme';` but that will emit the error. I don't like to add `@chakra-ui/theme` to my package.json to avoid future version mismatches.

Comment: hi Samuli, did you find the solution? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I ended up adding that module to eslint config file. I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding the dependency's dependency as an allowed module in eslint configuration as shown below. After that the `import defaultTheme from '@chakra-ui/theme';` will no longer emit an error.

```json
// .eslintrc.json
{
  "settings": {
    "node": {
      // Modules are installed with @chakra-ui/react
      "allowModules": ["@chakra-ui/theme", "@chakra-ui/theme-tools"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately `allowModules` didn't solve my case. But when I add the package to `peerDependencies`, the error goes away. I'm still not sure how this works, so I also googled an article which recommends placing the dependency in package.json as well. As it says, it will be installed only once and nothing wrong with it. This is how I ended up doing it.